# Moore–Penrose inverse for constrained least squares

Tags: least-squares, pseudoinverse

I would like to use the generalized Moore–Penrose inverse for solving a constrained least squares problem. More explicitly, I need to find the matrix A minimizing ||AX-B||, where matrices X and B are given. The problem is that components of matrices X and B are in [0,1] while components of A **must** be in [-1,1]. Any idea how to deal with this problem?

Comment: I realize the pseudoinverse solves least squares problems, but what makes you think it can be used to solve constrained least squares problems?  I haven't seen that before, although it would be interesting if it turns out to be true.

Comment: Do you mean that the components of $X$ (rather than $A$) are constrained to belong to $[-1,1]$?

Comment: I have no reason to think that it can be possible and perhaps I am forcing the use of the pseudo-inverse to solve that problem.

Comment: X and B are always in [0,1] and they are my inputs, so I must be able to find a matrix A in [-1,1] minimizing the expression above.

Comment: Oh, I see. It's unusual notation to have $X$ be given and have $A$ be the unknown.  Most people would expect the opposite.

Comment: I don't think you can use the pseudoinverse to solve this problem.  You can instead use an optimization algorithm such as the projected gradient method.

Comment: Exactly, but the notation holds. I am trying to train a Fuzzy Cognitive Map from one layer to the next one, where X denotes the inputs, A denotes the weight matrix connecting a layer with the next one, while B represents the expected outputs. So, my target is the weight matrix.